# My app works fine in emulator, but crashes when run in real device

Tags: android

Sorry if my question is stupid thing. But I really need help.

I have developed a android app (SdkVersion 27), and it run fine in android emulator. But some days ago, I try to install and run it in my real android device (Android 6.0.1). It give a crash "Unfortunately, myApp has stopped".

I was try to search, and read carefully error log. But it still not work.

Below is error log in Debug frame

**My solutions**

> binary xml file line #0: error inflating class imageview
>
> you have to see if your image has become drawable-v23 or v24 which might be higher than your mobile os level, Make sure to avoid creating drawable version image in project
>
> example In drawable folder ~> "ic_contact(v24)"
>
> Below answer save my day:
>
> [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47848817/6300438)

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
/data/app/vn.edu.hcmut.orderfood-1/lib/arm
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/aaaabbbbbb:  Name like '%%%'
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
                        motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@f906b95
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5638b68 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
           Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0700ba (t=6 e=186) (error -75)
            Failure getting entry for 0x7f0700ba (t=6 e=186) (error -75)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: vn.edu.hcmut.orderfood, PID: 17894
              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class ImageView
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                  at vn.edu.hcmut.orderfood.home_menu_search.MenuItemAdapter.getView(MenuItemAdapter.java:35)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2934)
                  at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1069)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20195)
                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20195)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.onMeasure(CardView.java:258)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20195)
                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20195)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1632)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20195)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20195)
                  at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:2109)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:510)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20195)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20195)
                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1028)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20195)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20195)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20195)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20195)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20195)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3094)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20195)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2646)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1601)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1893)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
                at android.view.ViewRo
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: Hongbao
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: Hongbao
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: Hongbao
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: Hongbao
          (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 37 with tag d74deda900000000{3612208553,0} uid -1, pid: 17894, getuid(): 10164
I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 42 with tag d74deda900000000{3612208553,0} uid -1, pid: 17894, getuid(): 10164
I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 37
I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 42
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17894 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: "              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class ImageView" Look at all of your XML layout files. Which one contains an ImageView on line #26?

Comment: It works. thank you for supporting me. I will update solution on my question.

Comment: @LuanPham It seems you have resolved your question. Instead of adding solution to your question, edit out the solution from the question and add it as a new answer.