# I am getting the following error in Image View in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I am running the project, it stops running when I click on login button.
I am getting the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.user.aarogya, PID: 29045
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.aarogya/com.example.user.aarogya.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2488)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5613)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.user.aarogya.Home.onCreate(Home.java:11)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6362)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5613) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:786)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.user.aarogya.Home.onCreate(Home.java:11) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6362) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5613) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060055
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1369)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getValue(MiuiResources.java:146)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:77)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:67)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:181)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:105)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.user.aarogya.Home.onCreate(Home.java:11) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6362) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5613) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

I have designed the UI components on the xml myself still it is showing this error. The application runs fine but stops working once I click on the button Login. This is active_Home.xml (which I guess is where you will find the error.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bac"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blue"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/camera"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/camera" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="159dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/community"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/community"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:text="COMMUNITY" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="131dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/complaints"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/complaints"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:text="COMPLAINTS" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="135dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/geot"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/geotag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/complaints"

        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:text="@string/geotag"
        tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/home"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run the xml file without code i;e empty, it calls it. But with this following code it does not.
Let me know if more code is required.

Comment: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060055
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1369)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getValue(MiuiResources.java:146) This means background or src image does not exists.

Comment: can you show me your onClick code.

Comment: please show your activity or fragment code?

Comment: In which folder is your camera image is stored..?

Comment: you might forgot to add image view reference. 
i.e imageview = (imageView) (Ri.id.imageview);

Comment: You are simply missing a resource from drawable folder.

Comment: @Tripti Dhiman refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37622725/5939) or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526417/binary-xml-file-line-0-error-inflating-class-imageview/47526543) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

All images may not be available in the drawable folder. Make sure also to include the images in the v21 and v24 folders.