# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class android.view.View

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I want to know why View is not working for notification layout.

[InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621934/inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflating-class-imageview)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagenotileft"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Bytepaper"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:background="@color/greyTextColor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNotifMail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Bytepaper"
        android:textColor="@color/greyTextColor" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:background="@color/greyTextColor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNotifTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Bytepaper"
        android:textColor="@color/greyTextColor" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please see I have used `<View/>` tag.

Comment: i think something wrong with greyTextColor

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the complete [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174).

Answer (score 1):

Change image view code to below code

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagenotileft"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_icon" />
```